# Why is these 2 javascript calls to addEventListener have different result

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can you help me to understand why these two JavaScript functions have different results when `console.log(self)` is executed?

The first code:

```
var test = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    document.getElementById('show-button').addEventListener('click', self.showButton, false);
  },

  showButton: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
  }
}
test.init();
```

Will result the following on the console when button show is clicked:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="show-button" title="Show the list">Show</button>
```

Whereas the second code:

```
var test = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    
    function show() {
      self.showButton();
    }
    
    document.getElementById('show-button').addEventListener('click', show, false);
  },

  showButton: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
  }
}
test.init();
```

Will result the following on the console when button show is clicked:

```
Object {init: function, showButton: function}
```

Comment: Aaaah... the `this` context... One of the most troubling concepts in JS :) And maybe in other languages too?

Comment: The first script binds the button to `showButton`, because you're setting it as event handler directly. In the second script however, while it does bind the button to `show()`'s `this`, you're calling `self.showButton()`, and `self` still refers to the object as per the `init` call, thus binding the object to `showButton`.

Comment: Related:[How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Btw, you can "fix" this by binding `show`'s context to `showButton`: `(self.showButton.bind(this))();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you pass `self.showButton` reference to the `addEventListener`. It'll then be executed in the context of the element applied to, in this example the button, so `this` will refer to that button.

In the second example your making a closure to capture your object instance thanks to the `show` method. So `show` is applied to the button, and then `show` calls `showButton` on your object instance.

To avoid this, you can use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function which does this exact job :

```js
var test = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    document.getElementById('show-button').addEventListener('click', self.showButton.bind(self), false);
  },

  showButton: function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
  }
}
test.init();
```

```html
<button id="show-button">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to how you pass the function to the event listener

1) document.getElementById('show-button').addEventListener('click', show, false);

Show is just a function (this = undefined) and this will be bound to the element.

2) document.getElementById('show-button').addEventListener('click', self.showButton, false);

self.showButton is an attribute (type function) which has already this bound to self (test object)

[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)